# Disable "Load at Startup" checkbox in Add-Ons list

Tags: packages, documentation, paclets

When a package comes with documentation, it will show up in the Installed Add-Ons list in the Documentation Center. This list can be accessed at `guide/InstalledAddOns` or using the link at the lower right of the documentation home page.

For my package, I get a Load Now button which loads the package, and three radio buttons for Automatic, Manual and Startup loading.  Automatic is disabled, the other two are active.

[image]

**How can I disable the Startup setting, or just disable these radio boxes completely?**

Setting it to Startup loading loads the package when Mathematica starts.  However, startup loading fails, breaks the package state, and even breaks some Mathematica `Import` functionality for the rest of session.  I don't fully understand why, but I *think* it's because the package attempts to `Import` some configuration when it is loaded and some `Import` functionality can't properly load during kernel initialization.  I'm not sure.  I just want to disable this

Answer (score 1):

These radio boxes are present if [`PacletInfo.m`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132064/12) has the `Kernel` or `Application` extension.  It cannot be disabled.

Whether to show it is decided by the `loadStateRadioPresent` fuction in `Documentation.m` in the paclet manager sources (see `PacletInformation["PacletManager"]` for location).