# PacletInfo.m documentation project

Tags: packages, paclets

[Packages can be made into paclets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131101/12), which provides easy distribution and versioning.  The paclet metadata is in the `PacletInfo.m` file. The PacletInfo settings also determine how the paclet can extend Mathematica: e.g. provide new functions for the kernel (a usual package), new palettes or stylesheets for the Front End, etc.

**What settings and extensions can be used in a `PacletInfo.m` file and what are their effects?**

Documenting these will be very useful for people who develop and publish packages.

---

Related posts:

- [How to distribute Mathematica packages as paclets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131101/12)
- [What is the purpose of the Kernel and Application extensions in PacletInfo.m?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130359/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-kernel-and-application-extensions-in-pacletinfo-m)
- [Create and deploy your own paclets in the Workbench](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/961186)
- [Create your own Paclet Site](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/968760?p_p_auth=VCLLf3ed)

Comment: Thank you so much for creating this post! For everyone's notice, I'm trying to finally create the functionality of *deploying a package* with the IntelliJ IDEA automatically. In the easiest case, it is just packing the sources into a `.zip` for extraction in a place where it can be loaded. However, deploying a paclet seems to be the future and the more consistent way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could not find this information before reading your post. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is a community project to produce useful documentation for `PacletInfo.m`.  Feel free to edit and improve this answer.

---

While the Paclet Manager is loaded from `.mx` files, its plain text `.m` sources are also available.  Much of the information in this post comes from the comments in those source files.  See `SystemOpen@Lookup[PacletInformation["PacletManager"], "Location"]`, especially `Extension.m` and `Paclet.m`.

Some other information comes from `PacletInfo.m` files that come with Mathematica:

```
paclets = Import[#, "Package"] & /@ FileNames["PacletInfo.m", $InstallationDirectory, Infinity];
```

as well as the [GitLink](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink) package.

---

## Introduction

Paclets are a format and distribution mechanism for packages or other resources that can extend Mathematica. The paclet is described by the `PacletInfo.m` file. This file is used by the PacletManager, which is built into the Wolfram Language.

When would a Mathematica user want to create a `PacletInfo.m` file?

This is generally useful when building [packages or applications](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/applications/introduction.html). Having this file allows [integrating documentation into the Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/documentationpaclets/index.html), or [bundling the package into a `.paclet` file and installing it with `PacletInstall`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131101/12).  The file is also recognized in applications installed into `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` or `$BaseDirectory/Applications` manually (the usual way) and not using `PacletInstall`.

In addition to Paclets installed into a base directory, the `PacletDirectoryAdd` command can be used to add a directory containing paclets to the PacletManager so that it is recognized by the Mathematica FrontEnd and `Needs`. This allows a paclet or a library of multiple paclets to reside anywhere, such as a network drive where it can be accessed by multiple users.

Todd Gayley gave [a presentation about paclets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLMgZqNepsU&list=PLxn-kpJHbPx1UF_0HngWHKfoVtAEsi8pw&index=34) at Wolfram Technology conference 2019.

---

## Example

A sample `PacletInfo.m` file from [GitLink](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink):

```
Paclet[
    Name -> "GitLink",
    Version -> "2100.0",
    MathematicaVersion -> "10.1+",
    Root -> ".",
    Internal -> True,
    Extensions -> 
        {
            {"Kernel", Root -> ".", Context -> "GitLink`"},

            {"Documentation", Language -> "English"},

      {"LibraryLink"}
        }
]
```

Note: GitLink is eventually going to become part of Mathematica. The `Internal` flag may be related to this and may not be appropriate for user packages.

---

## Settings

These are some of the settings that can be given in PacletInfo files.  See the default values using

```
Normal[PacletManager`Paclet`Private`$piDefaults]
```

The following should generally be present in any PacletInfo file:

- `Name`, paclet name.  This can be used to refer to the paclet, e.g. `PacletFind["name"]` or `PacletUpdate["name"]`.
- `Version`, paclet version. Must be up to five `.`-separated numbers. If multiple versions of a paclet are installed, it is always the latest one that will be used.

  This value is parsed as `PadRight[ToExpression@StringSplit[version, "."], 5]`.

The following can affect whether the paclet may be loaded:

- `MathematicaVersion` (deprecated) or `WolframVersion` (current since M10), minimum compatible Mathematica version, e.g. `"10+"` or `"10.0.2+"`. The paclet will not load in incompatible versions.  As of M11.0, it defaults to `"10+"`.

  While the `MathematicaVersion` form is deprecated, using `MathematicaVersion -> "10+"` allows Mathematica 9 to correctly identify a paclet as incompatible. M9 doesn't understand `WolframVersion`.
- `SystemID`, compatible system types. Can be a string, a list of strings, or `All`. See [`$SystemID`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$SystemID.html) for possible values.  Defaults to `All`, and should be omitted unless your package is only compatible with certain operating systems.

Other settings:

- `Root`, *probably* the paclet root relative to `PacletInfo.m`. Not tested yet.
- `Loading`, can be `Manual`, `Automatic`, or `"Startup"`. Defaults to `Manual`, i.e. the package can be loaded with `Needs` as usual.  `Automatic` is allowed only when the `Symbols` argument of the `Kernel` extension is set (see below).  `"Startup"` causes the package to load at kernel startup.

  This setting will be exposed in the Documentation Center (see below) and can be changed by the user.

  *Warning:* Be careful if the package does more than issue definitions upon loading. Some operations do not work during kernel initialization and may even lock up the kernel.
- `Internal`, can be `True`/`False`, ???
- `Qualifier`, have seen values like `$SystemID`, ???

Paclets that provide the Documentation extension will be listed in the Documentation Center under `guide/InstalledAddOns`.

[image]

The following metadata will be listed for each package/paclet on that page:

- `Creator`, author name.
- `Description`, description.
- `Publisher`, publisher name.
- `Thumbnail`, relative path to an image file. Will be used as the package icon.  Should be 46 by 46 pixels.

  *Warning:* There are some problems with the thumbnail retrieval. Rescaling to 46×46 fails (small bug) and using a thumbnail causes high CPU usage in M11 while the add-ons list is open (but not in M10.x).
- `URL`, package homepage.

[image]

Other metadata:

These can be retrieved for installed paclets using `PacletInformation["name"]`

- `BuildNumber`, `Category`, `Copyright`, `License`, `Support`.

---

## Extensions

The `Extensions` setting contains a list of extensions, each in the form

```
{"ExtensionName", "Argument1" -> Value1, "Argument2" -> Value2, ...}
```

The possible extensions and their arguments are below.

### Application

Seems to work in a similar way to Kernel. Not sure what the difference is. At this moment I believe that one can (perhaps should) always use Kernel instead.

Arguments:

- `Root`, defaults to `"."` (same as Kernel extension)
- `Context`

### AutoCompletionData

???

Arguments:

- `Root`, points to a directory containing a `specialArgFunctions.tr` file, see [Argument completions for user defined functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129910/12) for more hints.

Hints: See `PacletFind["EntityFramework"]`

### ChannelFramework

???

Hints: See `PacletFind["DemoChannels"]` for the implementation of the `Demo:OneLiner` channel which is shown in ChannelListen -> Applications -> Chat.

### Documentation

Fully documented in the [Workbench Help](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/reference/projects/documentationextension.html).

Used to integrate documentation into the Documentation Center.

Will cause the application to show up in the auto-generated application list in the Documentation Center at `guide/InstalledAddOns`.

Arguments:

- `Language`, defaults to `All`
- `Root`, defaults to `"Documentation"`
- `Context`, rarely needed, use same argument in Kernel extension instead
- `MainPage`
- `LinkBase`
- `Resources`

Multiple instances of the Documentation extension can be used in the same PacletInfo file. For example, if multiple languages are supported there should be one extension for each language. For an example, see the `Parallel` paclet in `AddOns/Applications`.

The `LinkBase` argument is needed only in cases where documentation is stored in a different paclet from the code<sup>*</sup>. For an example, see the `Parallel` paclet in `AddOns/Applications` which links to the `ParallelTools` paclet.

The `Resources` should never need to be used by outside developers of paclets used in version 7+<sup>*</sup>.

### FrontEnd

Will cause subdirectories within the `FrontEnd` to be handled, e.g. `FrontEnd/Palettes`, `FrontEnd/StyleSheets`, `FrontEnd/SystemResources`, `FrontEnd/TextResources`.  These items will be recognized by the Front End, e.g. palettes will show up in the Palettes menu.

Arguments:

- `Root`, defaults to `"FrontEnd"`
- `WolframVersion`
- `SystemID`

References:

- [Show StyleSheets and Palettes from custom directory in Mathematica's Menu](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120976/5478)

### JLink

Will cause `.jar` files within the root (`"Java"` by default) to be added to the classpath.

Arguments:

- `Root`, defaults to `"Java"`
- `WolframVersion`
- `SystemID`

### Kernel

Makes the package loadable by `Needs`.

Arguments:

- `Root`, defaults to `"."` for compatibility but `"Kernel"` is also typical.  [`FindFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFile.html) resolves the specified context to this location during the first stage of its name resolution. See also [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133242/12](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133275/12).
- `Context`, package context or list of contexts. Used by `FindFile`.  Also causes `>>` documentation links to be added to usage messages when documentation is present.
- `Symbols`, a list of symbols that will trigger [autoloading](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AutomaticLoadingOfPackages.html) if `Loading -> Automatic` is set.  It is required for `Loading -> Automatic` to be a valid setting. Similar to [`DeclarePackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeclarePackage.html). Symbols can be given with full context, e.g. `` Symbols -> {"MyPack`MyFun1", "MyPack`MyFun2"} ``.
- `WolframVersion`
- `SystemID`
- `HiddenImport`

### LibraryLink

Arguments:

Will cause shared libraries within `LibraryResources/$SystemID` to be found by [`FindLibrary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindLibrary.html).

- `Root`, defaults to `LibraryResources`.
- `WolframVersion`
- `SystemID`

### Path

???

Arguments:

- `Base`
- `Root`
- `WolframVersion`
- `SystemID`

### Resource

The `Resource` extension can be used to create new extensions that are managed by the PacletManager and can be located using `PacletResources` or `PacletResource`. These functions cull the resources by SystemID, Wolfram Language version and Language, providing a system-independent method to manage arbitrary files that paclets depend on.

To use the resource in a package, use `PacletResource` to retrieve the path to the resource, then use that path in the package functions as appropriate.

An example is the `MachineLearning` paclet in `SystemFiles\Components`. It provides a number of system-specific libraries used by the component, and demonstrates how to use aliases for the resources.

`MachineLearning` defines a `"KenLM"` resource. To get the path to the system-appropriate resource, use `PacletResource["MachineLearning", "KenLM"]`. This returns `"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\11.0\\SystemFiles\\Components\\MachineLearning\
\\Resources\\Binaries\\Windows-x86-64\\lmplz.exe"` on a 64-bit Windows machine.

To find all paclets with a `"Libraries"` resource, use `PacletResources["Resource", "Libraries"]`. This returns two paclets and resource paths: `{{Paclet["Cryptography","1.0",<>],{"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\11.0\\SystemFiles\\Components\\Cryptography\\Resources\\Libraries"}},{Paclet["MachineLearning","1.0.0",<>],{"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\11.0\\SystemFiles\\Components\\MachineLearning\\Resources\\Libraries"}}}`

Arguments:

- `Root`
- `Resources`
- `SystemID`

`Root` is the path to the folder the resources are stored in, relative to the paclet directory.

`Resources` is a list of resources. Each resource can be defined as a string for the resource path or a list `{"Name", "Path"}` where `Name` is an alias to identify the resource. The path is relative to the `Root` path. The resource can be a file or directory.

`SystemID` must be used when resources are system specific.

---

<sup>*</sup> From personal correspondence with Todd Gayley, WRI

Comment: hmm, why aren't the references displaying after my edit?

Comment: @DavidCreech Thanks for the edit!  That's really Markdown syntax, don't worry about it, I'll fix it tomorrow when I'm less sleepy.

Comment: @Szabolcs have you seen the list in ``PacletManager`Paclet`Private`$pacletInfoSymbols``? Scraped that guy up and it has your list+ more. Most seem relatively self-explanatory though. Not sure what things like `HiddenImport` would do in the context of a paclet though.

Comment: @MB1965 Don't read in-memory definitions.  Look at the actual source code instead, which also have comments. I have seen it, and based on the sources I do not think that there is anything relevant in that variable that is not mentioned in the post.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm currently reading the source, amusingly enough. Occasionally one strikes gold doing so, but it seems you've mined this vein thoroughly enough maybe everything I could learn from it is on MSE already.

Comment: @MB1965 If you find something useful, feel free to edit the above post and add it.

Comment: @Szabolcs nothing of note found, really. I thought I would post an answer on your other question detailing how you can easily set up a paclet server with the cloud, though.

Comment: @Szabolcs have you seen ``FrontEnd`Private`LocateAutoCompletionData[]``? It seems to use the `"AutoCompletionData"` extension via `PacletResources`.

Comment: [In this Twitch video around 0:56](https://www.twitch.tv/videos/209206388), Stephen Wolfram mentioned that the Paclet functionality is going to be documented in the near future.  Thanks to Emerson Willard for pointing this out to me!

Comment: @Szabolcs 1.5y < near future;

Comment: It looks like `PacletResource` no longer exists in 12.3. At least, `PacletResource["MachineLearning", "KenLM"]` doesn't evaluate to anything. @Szabolcs What should we use instead?

Comment: @JEM_Mosig Looks like it's `PacletObject["MachineLearning"]["AssetLocation", "KenLM"]` now

Comment: @JEM_Mosig Indeed the answer is in the comment above. However, you can find the old paclet functions in the ``PacletManager` `` context, and their usage messages often give hints about what they are replaced with. Try ``?PacletManager`PacletResource`` to see this.

Comment: This is now documented in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Paclets.html.