# How to add frontend resources for using in package/paclets?

Tags: packages

I have some thumbnails that I want to use inside my package, which need to be loaded with `` FEPrivate`FrontEndResource ``. AFAIK those assets have to be placed in .tr files in this exact directory (on macOS):

*/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources*

Now of course one could manually copy them over on installation, but what if I'm using PacletInstall?  What are the best practices here for distribution?

Comment: They should be placed in ``pacletDirPath/FrontEnd/TextResources/resource.tr``. These get added to the resource path automatically by the PacletManager if `FrontEnd` is set in the extensions. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132065/38205 for more.

Comment: I believe you have my Qwant service connection installed. You can see how I handled the `"SystemResources"` equivalent by looking at that via: `SystemOpen@PacletFind["*_Qwant"][[1]]["Location"]`

Comment: You can also add them to `~Applications/Your application/FrontEnd/TextResources` which is what I do for modifying menus and contextual menus when my application is running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I tossed this in a comment, but it deserves some elaboration.

The appropriate place is the `"FrontEnd/TextResources"` subdirectory in your paclet.

You can see how WRI does this by looking at the CloudObject paclet:

```
PacletFind["CloudObject"][[1]]["Location"] // SystemOpen
```

You then need to add

```
{"FrontEnd", Prepend -> True}
```

As an extension in your PacletInfo.m

Szabolcs has more info [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132065/38205)

Finally, all the paclet manager does is add the text resource directories to:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {PrivatePaths, "TextResources"}]
```

And in fact you can see this is how the CloudObject system adds its resources:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {PrivatePaths, "TextResources"}][[1]]

FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Paclets", "Repository", 
  "CloudObject-11.2.1398", "FrontEnd", "TextResources"}, 
 "PacletManager" -> True, "Prepend" -> True]
```

Thus any arbitrary directory you want to use can be added like that, which gives you a way to dynamically set a directory at paclet loading.