# How to create multilingual documentation inside Wolfram Workbench?

Tags: documentation, workbench

I am relatively new to Mathematica package development. Currently I am trying to migrate a single .m file to a fully grown paclet for future maintainability and currently I am hitting a brick wall:

Is it possible using the Wolfram Workbench (the Eclipse version) to create documentation for multiple languages? At my university, we do not natively speak English, and the target group are fresh students.

From the following link [PacletInfo.m documentation project](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132064/pacletinfo-m-documentation-project/132065#132065) I take away that it is possible to add multiple languages.

My current approach: Manually edit `PacletInfo.m` to

```
    Extensions -> 
    {
        {"Documentation", Language -> "English"}, 
        {"Documentation", Language -> "German"}
    }
```

and copying the folder tree of `/Documentation/English/` to `/Documentation/German/`.

Problem: The Documentation subpage of the `PacletInfo.m` looks like it only manages the files in the standard folder `English/` and furthermore manually copying over a file to `German/ReferencePages/Symbols` from the English folders doesn't include this "german" docu-file in the build process.

If it isn't currently possible, what are up-to-date alternatives to documentation generation?