# PacletBuild ignores "Path" extension and doesn't include local data files

Tags: paclets

I'm trying to build my first paclet which includes a .txt data file. As per [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Paclets.html), I added `{"Path"}` to `"Extensions"` section in `PacletInfo.wl`, so that it now looks like this:

```
PacletObject[
    <|
        "Name" -> "WordGrid",
        "Version" -> "0.0.1",
        "WolframVersion" -> "13+",
        "Extensions" ->
            {
                {
                    "Path"
                },
                {
                    "Kernel",
                    "Root" -> "Kernel",
                    "Context" -> "WordGrid`"
                },
                {
                    "Documentation",
                    "Language" -> "English"
                }
            }
    |>
]
```

I put the data file under the paclet's root directory in `WordGrid/rusian_nouns.txt` and am now trying to access it from within the paclet with e.g. `Import["WordGrid/russian_nouns.txt"]`:

```
RussianNouns[] := RussianNouns[] =
    ToLowerCase /@ StringSplit[Import["WordGrid/russian_nouns.txt"]];
```

Everything seems to work during the development: the following code, executed in a fresh kernel, returns the list of Russian nouns as expected:

```
PacletDirectoryLoad[NotebookDirectory[] <> "WordGrid"]
Needs["WordGrid`"]
RussianNouns[]
```

However, after I build the paclet with

```
Needs["PacletTools`"]
PacletBuild[NotebookDirectory[] <> "WordGrid"]
```

I can't see the `.txt` file in the `build` directory or the manifest, and the paclet file itself is too small to contain my list of words.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a bug in `BuildPacket`: when I create the paclet using `CreatePacletArchive` and install the result, everything works as expected.

Comment: I think you're supposed to use "Resource" extension, then it will be included in the build file. Specifying empty root `Root->""` with "Path" extension will enable you to use it with Import. Also you usually name each resource (i.e. "RussianNouns") and path to it can be extracted with `PacletObject["WordGrid"]["AssetLocation", "RussianNouns"]` (in earlier versions it was `PacletResource`, but it got scrubbed it seems).

Comment: Thanks @swish for the answer! "Resource" extension is undocumented; did you mean "Asset"? In the documentation link I posted above, that's what is suggested. For my needs, I want to avoid explicit resource/asset enumeration.

Also, the documentation, in the subsection "Path", mentions nothing about the "Root" key - everything should work as I describe above.

Comment: Maybe I need to include "Root"->"" indeed, but in that case the documentation (and some videos like https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?v=3537) should probably be updated - e.g., in the link above, at 13:20 they show usage of "Path" without "Root" and at 16:42 the expected behavior of `ReadList`.

Comment: "Resource" extension is described a little bit [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132064/pacletinfo-m-documentation-project/). [Here](https://github.com/WolframResearch/codeparser/blob/ac0b5c43ca10c69b086502d95e735fdd0ad4323f/CodeParser/PacletInfo.wl.in) is an example of using it in the wild.

Comment: I think "Asset" and "Resource" are the same thing and can be used both, not sure why official documentation uses one, but all the developers use another one though :)

Comment: I'm not an insider, but could it be legacy code? At least in the official documentation, it's recommended to use `PacletObject` with an Association as an argument and not plain `Paclet` anymore...

Comment: The PacletTools itself also is a good example: `SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{PacletObject["PacletTools"]["Location"],"PacletInfo.wl"}]`. And it uses old `Paclet` format, but with new "Asset" extension. I would recommend following the documentation as much as possible.

Comment: Yep, it looks like "Resource" is much more common than "Asset", and "Path" is not used often (but is used some):

`With[{all = PacletFind[<|"WolframVersion" -> All|>]}, Length@Select[all, x |-> MemberQ[x["Extensions"], #, All]] & /@ {"Path", "Asset", "Resource", _}]` returns `{3, 4, 84, 350}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of PacletBuild. This behavior is intentional, though I can understand why it seems like a bug.

You can fix this by moving any files you intend to load via file path name lookup into a subdirectory (name doesn't matter), and modifying the `"Path"` extension to point at that subdirectory. For example:

- File: `WordGrid/Files/russian_nouns.txt`
- Extension: `{"Path", "Root" -> "Files"}`
- Lookup code: `Import["WordGrid/russian_nouns.txt"]` (unchanged)

---

The issue is that `PacletBuild` uses [`PacletExtensionFiles`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PacletTools/ref/PacletExtensionFiles) to determine what files are associated with each entry in the paclet `"Extensions"` list, and that `"Path"` extensions that use the implicit default `"Root" -> "."` have no well-defined definition for that operation.

For example, consider `"Asset"` extensions. The associated files of an `"Asset"` extension are obvious and explicit: they are simply whatever files are specified in the `"Asset"` extension options.

However, the `"Path"` extension is a bit of an unusual case, because there is no way to statically determine what files the user *intends* to refer to via path lookup, which means that potentially *any* file in the entire paclet directory could be named.

`PacletExtensionFiles` makes the assumption that every file is associated with a particular extension; without specifying a custom `"Root"` location, `"Path"` extensions violate that assumption.

By specifying a `"Root"` location that isn't simply the entire paclet's root directory, `PacletExtensionFiles` accepts that more narrow subdirectory as being unambiguous.

---

Edit: For an illustration of the above, here is the result of `PacletExtensionFiles[PacletObject["ExamplePaclet"], "Path"]`
on a paclet with a `{"Path"}` extension:

```
<|{"Path", <||>} -> Missing["NotAvailable"]|>
```

vs. with a `{"Path", "Root" -> "Files"}` extension:

```
<|{"Path", <|"Root" -> "Files"|>} -> {"/Users/connorgray/Desktop/ExamplePaclet/Files/Data.wl"}|>
```

---

`PacletBuild` should arguably issue a warning about this issue, and suggest the fix I describe above.

Comment: Thank you Connor for a detailed answer! May I suggest that the documentation should be modified accordingly? My intuition about how `Path` extension should behave is based solely on the examples I found in the standard documentation and in various YouTube videos, all of which show {"Path"} without an explicit `Root` option.

Comment: @VictorK. That is a reasonable suggestion. I can also update PacletBuild to issue a clear warning about this behavior, so users won't silently have missing files, like you ran into.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, one other thought I have is that the additional source of confusion is the behavior of `CreatePacletArchive`, which does include all files when `Path` is enabled even without the `Root` option (but looks like you are going to eventually deprecate it?).

Comment: @VictorK. I just wanted to give you an update that this is fixed in the upcoming WL v13.2.1 bugfix release. In that version, PacletBuild[..] will return an error when building a paclet with a `{"Path"}` extension. The fix is as described in my answer: adding a `"Root" -> "Something"` value and putting the desired files in that directory.

Comment: @VictorK. (Oops, didn't mean to post that previous comment so soon.)

Regarding `CreatePacletArchive`, you can think of this as a lower-level function that simply bundles up a collection of files into the archive format used by .paclet files. `CreatePacletArchive` is analogous to `Compress` is that it is mostly agnostic as to the content of the directory being archived. `PacletBuild[..]` is the higher-level function intended for most use-cases.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @ConnorGray for providing an update, and of course for fixing it in the first place!